# Python: Apply function to each row of a Pandas DataFrame and return **new data frame**

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply a function to each row of a data frame. The tricky part is that the function returns a new data frame for each processed row. Assume the columns of this data frame can easily be derived from the processed row.

At the end the result should be all these data frames (1 for each processed row) concatenated. I intentionally do not provide sample code, because the simplest of solution proposal will do, as long as the 'tricky' part if fulfilled.

I have spend hours trying digging through docs and stackoverflow to find a solution. As usual the pandas docs are so devoid of practical examples aside the simplest of operations that I just couldn't figure it out. I also made sure to not miss any duplicate questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need to return a dataframe if you just concatenate them at the end?  Nothing in your question explains why this 'requirement' is relevant.  In fact, you are likely processing the data inefficiently if you are thinking in terms of rows instead of columns.

Comment: ... have you tried the `pd.DataFrame.apply` method? It seems to do *exactly* what you want.

Comment: @Alexander I actually do need this requirement. 

Consider this concocted example: Each row in the data table is a the first name of a person. The function to be applied on each row will take that name and by whatever logic (that references external objects/data frames) will return 5 numerical features associated with the name. Now I very much need the name and its 5 features to be in DataFrame format, i.e. 5 rows with 2 columns: Name|Feature

And the same goes for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, but I doubt you need to create separate dataframes.

The example below shows how you can take a dataframe, subset it to your columns of interest, apply a function `foo` to one of the columns and then apply a second function `bar` that returns multiple values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['john', 'nancy', 'jolly'],
    'last_name': ['smith', 'drew', 'rogers'],
    'A': [1, 4, 7],
    'B': [2, 5, 8],
    'C': [3, 6, 9]
})

>>> df
first_name  last_name   A   B   C
0   john    smith   1   2   3
1   nancy   drew    4   5   6
2   jolly   rogers  7   8   9

def foo(first_name):
    return 2 if first_name.startswith('j') else 1

def bar(first_name):
    return (2, 0) if first_name.startswith('j') else (1, 3)

columns_of_interest = ['first_name', 'A']

df_new = pd.concat([
    df[columns_of_interest].assign(x=df.first_name.apply(foo)),
    df.first_name.apply(bar).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

>>> df_new
first_name  A   x   0   1
0   john    1   2   2   0
1   nancy   4   1   1   3
2   jolly   7   2   2   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the function you are applying to each row is called `f`

```
pd.concat({i: f(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()})
```

Working example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

def f(row):
    return pd.concat([row] * 2, keys=['x', 'y']).unstack().drop('C', 1).assign(S=99)

pd.concat({i: f(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()})

      A   B   D   E   S
0 x   0   1   3   4  99
  y   0   1   3   4  99
1 x   5   6   8   9  99
  y   5   6   8   9  99
2 x  10  11  13  14  99
  y  10  11  13  14  99
3 x  15  16  18  19  99
  y  15  16  18  19  99
4 x  20  21  23  24  99
  y  20  21  23  24  99
```

Or

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: f(x.squeeze()))


      A   B   D   E   S
0 x   0   1   3   4  99
  y   0   1   3   4  99
1 x   5   6   8   9  99
  y   5   6   8   9  99
2 x  10  11  13  14  99
  y  10  11  13  14  99
3 x  15  16  18  19  99
  y  15  16  18  19  99
4 x  20  21  23  24  99
  y  20  21  23  24  99
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way - although I note the .apply is possibly what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(7)

orig=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,3))

orig.columns=(['F1','F2','F3'])

res=[]


for i,r in orig.iterrows():
    tot=0
    for col in r:
        tot=tot+col
    rv={'res':tot}
    a=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rv,orient='index',dtype=np.float64)
    res.append(a)


res[0].head()
```

Should return something like this

```
{'res':10}
```